# Выборка ip из бд mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю выборку `ip` адресов, интересуют все результаты кроме данного диапазона (`55.249.0.0 - 55.249.255.255`):

```
SELECT ip, count(*) FROM dbip **AND INET_ATON(ip) 
NOT IN (BETWEEN INET_ATON('55.249.0.0') AND INET_ATON('55.249.255.255'))** IN GROUP BY ip
```

Comment: Вложенный запрос сделайте на тот диапазон что не интересует, а потом делайте чтобы в него не входило.

Comment: И у вас наверное вместо первого and должно быть where

Answer (score 0):

Запрос-то идеологически правильный, а вот синтаксис - подкачал...

```
SELECT ip, count(*) 
FROM dbip 
WHERE INET_ATON(ip) NOT BETWEEN INET_ATON('55.249.0.0') AND INET_ATON('55.249.255.255')
GROUP BY ip
```

Правда, с производительностью у него будет грустно - функция от поля напрочь убивает возможность использовать индексы. Если есть возможность, то IP надо хранить в формате числа, а не строки, и преобразовывать-форматировать при получении из таблицы - тогда индекс по полю сможет нормально работать и в этом, и в других запросах. В крайнем случае - форматировать поле при хранении в фиксированную длину групп, с ведущими нулями.

Comment: спасибо, вопрос решился